# What type should be mLoaderManager and how to declare it?

Tags: android-studio, loader

This is the code from the [RxJava for Android App Development book, p.20](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/rxjava-for-android-app-development.csp)  use RxJava with the Loader. What type should be mLoaderManager and how to declare it?

```
private static class LoaderInitOnSubscribe implements Observable.OnSubscribe<Story> {
//...
@Override
public void call(final Subscriber<? super Story> subscriber) {
    mLoaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_ID, mLoaderArgs, new LoaderCallbacks<Story>() {
        @Override
        public Loader<Story> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundleargs) {
            return new StoryLoader(mContext);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Story> loader, Story data) {
            subscriber.onNext(data);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Story> loader) {}
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LoaderManager` is obtained from an `Activity` via [`getLoaderManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLoaderManager()) or from a `Fragment` via [`getLoaderManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getLoaderManager()).